# Why does my multi-parameter chi-square get stuck in error loop?

Tags: python, chi-squared

I'm trying to carry out a multi-parameter fit using the `lmfit` module in python, subject to the constraint that some of the parameter groups must sum to one.

e.g. Say I have parameters B1_0 and B1_1 in my chi-square, I set up my parameters with something like `params.add('B1_0', value=0.5, min=0, max=1)` for the first and `params.add('B1_1', expr='1-B1_0-B1_2')`  for the second. I can then use the `minimize` method to find the best fit of my model to my data.

In my code it is not this simple; there are many auto-generated parameters to fit so I use a method like this:

```
for term in listOfTerms:
    con = constraint(term,listOfTerms)    # finds the constraint (all sum to 1)
    params.add(term,value=getValue(term),expr=con)
```

where the method `getValue(term)` returns the value from another fitting method that is known to minimize the chi-square. When I try to run my code I get an error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/MPhys/chisquare.py", line 123, in <module>
    result = minimize(objfunc,params,args=(trans,sum_in,sum_out,data))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 467, in minimize
    iter_cb=iter_cb, scale_covar=scale_covar, **fit_kws)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.prepare_fit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 219, in prepare_fit
    self.update_constraints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 122, in update_constraints
    self.__update_paramval(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 109, in __update_paramval
    self.__update_paramval(dep)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 109, in __update_paramval
    self.__update_paramval(dep)
```

...
...
etc., which terminates with:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 109, in __update_paramval
    self.__update_paramval(dep)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit-0.7-py2.7.egg/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 106, in __update_paramval
    par = self.params[name]
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I don't know why lmfit is throwing errors in this fit. Does anyone have an idea? It 'works' without the constraints but give unusable results.

Comment: Most likely b/c the starting parameters are not good. Try to pick reasonable starting values and see what happens if you can. Also, the mpfit and kmpfit packages are possibly more robust.

Comment: That's the thing, to see if its running properly I pass it good values to begin with. I'll see how mpfit and kmpfit handle the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular problem, the parameters are set with some constraints by the `params.add` method from the lmfit module. The error is occurring because the program is trying to apply the constraint BEFORE some of the parameters are defined.

One can work around this by first defining all of the parameters and then implementing the constraints with `params['<enter parameter here>'].expr = '<expression defining constraint>`.

For example:

```
# create a set of Parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('amp',   value= 10,  min=0)
params.add('decay', value= 0.1) 
params.add('shift', value= 0.0, min=-np.pi/2., max=np.pi/2)
params.add('omega', value= 0.01)

params['amp'].expr = '1-decay-shift-omega'
```

Hope this helps others using this module!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, the error can also be reached when there are parameter interdependencies in the expressions. I was recently working on a problem which required the following constraints and received the same message:

```
#define mr as mi/mii
params['mr'].expr='mi/mii'
params['mi'].expr='mii*(mr)'
params['mii'].expr='mi*(1/mr)'
```

As here the expressions all depend on one another, so lmfit cannot figure it out. I hope this helps other people viewing this message. The error can be fixed by removing some of the interdependence in the expressions. This seems like an issue that could be solved by changing the source code to accept these types of dependencies.

Cheers